# Extract Menu Link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get all menu page link , in order to fetch product from each menu page , 
Here is HTML code for Menu

```
<nav id="cavas_menu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="leo-top-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav megamenu"><li class=" parent dropdown aligned-left ">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle has-category" data-toggle="dropdown" target="_self"><span class="menu-title">Categories</span><b class="caret"></b></a><div class="dropdown-sub dropdown-menu" style="width:400px"><div class="dropdown-menu-inner"><div class="row"><div class="mega-col col-sm-6"> <div class="mega-col-inner "><div class="leo-widget"><div class="widget-subcategories">
        <div class="widget-inner">
        <div class="menu-title">Home</div>
        <ul>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                    <a href="https://www.vapors.com/14-e-juices" title="E-Juices" class="img">
                        E-Juices 
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                    <a href="https://www.vapors.com/15-mods" title="Mods" class="img">
                        Mods 
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                    <a href="https://www.vapors.com/17-accessories" title="Accessories" class="img">
                        Accessories 
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                    <a href="https://www.vapors.com/19-starter-kits" title="Starter Kits" class="img">
                        Starter Kits 
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                    <a href="https://www.vapors.com/21-ego" title="Ego" class="img">
                        Ego 
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                    <a href="https://www.vapors.com/27-rda" title="RDA" class="img">
                        RDA 
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                    <a href="https://www.vapors.com/28-regulated-mods" title="Regulated Mods" class="img">
                        Regulated Mods 
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                    <a href="https://www.vapors.com/29-clearomizer" title="Clearomizer" class="img">
                        Clearomizer 
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                    <a href="https://www.vapors.com/30-drip-tips" title="Drip Tips" class="img">
                        Drip Tips 
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                    <a href="https://www.vapors.com/33-sales" title="Sales" class="img">
                        Sales 
                    </a>
                </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
 </div></div></div><div class="mega-col col-sm-6"> <div class="mega-col-inner "><div class="leo-widget"> <div class="widget-products">
        <div class="menu-title">
        New Products
    </div>
        <div class="widget-inner">

                <div class="product-block">










             <div class="product-container clearfix">   
                    <div class="image ">
                            <a class="product_img_link" href="https://www.vapors.com/rda/794-plume-veil-v25-limited-ed.html" title="Plume Veil V2.5 Limited Ed." itemprop="url">
                                <img class="replace-2x img-responsive" src="https://www.vapors.com/307-home_default/plume-veil-v25-limited-ed.jpg" alt="Plume Veil V2.5 Limited Ed." title="Plume Veil V2.5 Limited Ed." itemprop="image">
                        </a>
                                                            <span class="new-box">
                                    <span class="new-label">New</span>
                                </span>
                                                </div>
                    <div class="product-meta">
                            <h5 itemprop="name">
                                                                <a class="product-name" href="https://www.vapors.com/rda/794-plume-veil-v25-limited-ed.html" title="Plume Veil V2.5 Limited Ed." itemprop="url">
                                    Plume Veil V2.5 Limited Ed.
                                </a>
                            </h5>
                            <p class="product-desc" itemprop="description">

                            </p>    
                                                            <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="content_price">
                                                                            <span itemprop="price" class="price product-price">
                                            $89.99                                      </span>
                                        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="1">
                                                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                </div>                  



             <div class="product-container clearfix">   
                    <div class="image ">
                            <a class="product_img_link" href="https://www.vapors.com/rda/793-plume-veil-v25.html" title="Plume Veil V2.5" itemprop="url">
                                <img class="replace-2x img-responsive" src="https://www.vapors.com/306-home_default/plume-veil-v25.jpg" alt="Plume Veil V2.5" title="Plume Veil V2.5" itemprop="image">
                        </a>
                                                            <span class="new-box">
                                    <span class="new-label">New</span>
                                </span>
                                                </div>
                    <div class="product-meta">
                            <h5 itemprop="name">
                                                                <a class="product-name" href="https://www.vapors.com/rda/793-plume-veil-v25.html" title="Plume Veil V2.5" itemprop="url">
                                    Plume Veil V2.5
                                </a>
                            </h5>
                            <p class="product-desc" itemprop="description">
                                This all new version of the Veil is a Sub-Ohm V2.5 RDA by...
                            </p>    
                                                            <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="content_price">
                                                                            <span itemprop="price" class="price product-price">
                                            $89.99                                      </span>
                                        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="1">
                                                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                </div>                  


        </div>



    </div>
</div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></li><li class="active">
                        <a href="https://www.vapors.com/14-e-juices" target="_self" class="has-category"><span class="menu-title">E-Juices</span></a></li><li class="">
                        <a href="https://www.vapors.com/15-mods" target="_self" class="has-category"><span class="menu-title">Mods</span></a></li><li class="">
                        <a href="https://www.vapors.com/28-regulated-mods" target="_self" class="has-category"><span class="menu-title">Regulated Mods</span></a></li><li class="">
                        <a href="https://www.vapors.com/27-rda" target="_self" class="has-category"><span class="menu-title">RDA</span></a></li><li class="">
                        <a href="https://www.vapors.com/19-starter-kits" target="_self" class="has-category"><span class="menu-title">Starter Kits</span></a></li><li class="">
                        <a href="https://www.vapors.com/29-clearomizer" target="_self" class="has-category"><span class="menu-title">Clearomizer</span></a></li><li class="">
                        <a href="https://www.vapors.com/30-drip-tips" target="_self" class="has-category"><span class="menu-title">Drip tips</span></a></li><li class="">
                        <a href="https://www.vapors.com/21-ego" target="_self" class="has-category"><span class="menu-title">Ego</span></a></li><li class="">
                        <a href="https://www.vapors.com/17-accessories" target="_self" class="has-category"><span class="menu-title">Accessories</span></a></li><li class="sales">
                        <a href="https://www.vapors.com/33-sales" target="_self" class="has-category"><span class="menu-title">Sales</span></a></li></ul>
        </div>
</nav>
```

I need to get all href link and click on each link to perform some action .

here is code which i tried but getting output as null :

```
 List<WebElement> cat=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='cavas_menu']"));


     for (WebElement catmenu : cat){

         System.out.println(catmenu.getAttribute("href"));


     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple issues with your code.

1) Your XPath will only have 1 element in the `List<>` because there is only one element with `id=cavas_menu`.

```
<nav id="cavas_menu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
```

and it's not what you are looking for. You want the links inside that menu.

2) The second issue is that Selenium will only interact with visible elements and the elements (links) you want are inside of a menu so you will need to hover the menu to expose and scrape them.

I tested the code below and it works.

```
driver.get("https://www.vapors.com/");

// dismiss Age Certification dialog
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.over-18")).click();

// hover the menu to expose it
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.menu-title"))).build().perform();

// gather the links and print the HREFs
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.img"));
for (WebElement link : links)
{
    System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Comment: The one addition I would suggest would be to use an explicit wait to resolve the links on the page.  *WebDriverWait* in combination with *ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("a.img")))* to ensure the dropdown contents have time to become visible before attempting to resolve them.

Comment: @Jeremiah I general I would agree but in this case I didn't find it was necessary. I usually write code without waits and then add them as I find they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

i've looked trough your code, here is a slightly modified version:

```
  public void sample() {
    driver.get("C:\\Users\\dmalinovschi\\Desktop\\index.html");
        List<WebElement> listElements;
        listElements =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='clearfix']/a"));

        for (int i=0; i<listElements.size(); i++) {
            String link = listElements.get(i).getAttribute("href");
           System.out.println(link);
        }
}
```

Here is the variant with opening them in new tabs:

```
  public void sample() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("base website link");

        List<WebElement> listElements;
        listElements =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='clearfix']/a"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Actions control =   builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);
        for (int i=0; i<listElements.size(); i++) {

            String link = listElements.get(i).getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println(link);

            control.click(listElements.get(i));
            builder.build().perform();;
            Thread.sleep(2000);

        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply , but i am getting an error as , invalid selector

Comment: Do you need to open those links on a new tab ? Sorry, have written the code quickly. Check the edit now, i've tested it

Comment: Dude, did you try it ?

Comment: Dude, you need to relax. When he tries it, he will let you know. Why the hurry?

Comment: Curiosity :) Si,ple as that

Comment: Thanks Buddy It Works